Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined in the frontend code using React + Vite + Firebase
I am developing a frontend application using React and Vite. I have cloned a React/Bootstrap theme template and am modifying it for my project. However, I have encountered an error when attempting to configure and initialize Firebase for authentication.
Here is the code I am trying to implement:
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

console.log(process.env);

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);  // gives us an auth instance

export default auth;   // in order to use this auth instance elsewhere

However, when I try to run the project and open the console window in Google Chrome, I receive the following error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at firebase.js?t=1714400003156:4:13

I am unsure as to why this error is occurring, especially as I have ensured that the process.env instances in my code correctly correspond to variables in my .env file.

process is a server-side variable only. Accessing process.env is only possible from the client if your build tool is configured to replace references to process.env with their literal values in the outputted JavaScript.

It looks like Vite uses a different syntax for accessing those environment variables (docs). import.meta.env

when I use import.meta.env instead of process.env, then I got this error: Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key). Is this env related error?

Seems separate, like your variable is now accessible, but has an incorrect value?

sorry. When I console the env variable console.log(import.meta.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY); it outputs undefined. Ofc, .env file is okay

I have fixed issues myself and I just want to elaborate a little further on my post for anyone out there experiencing a similar issue.
It came to my attention that when using the Vite build tool in a project, one unique requirement is that all environment variables need to be prefaced with VITE_. Vite only exposes variables on the import.meta.env object that start with this prefix. So, don't expect it to expose variables beginning with REACT_APP_.
In my specific case, I had to rename all the environment variables listed in my .env file from REACT_APP_FIREBASE_ to VITE_FIREBASE_.
now .env should look something like this:
VITE_FIREBASE_APIKEY=your_api_key 
VITE_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN=your-auth-domain 
VITE_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=your-project_id 
VITE_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET=your_storage_bucket 
VITE_FIREBASE_MESSAGE_SENDER_ID=your-message-sender-id 
VITE_FIREBASE_APP_ID=your-firebase-id 
VITE_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID=your-measurement-id

Moreover, within my JavaScript file, I needed to substitute all mentions of REACT_APP_FIREBASE_ with VITE_FIREBASE_.
This is a sample of how the new code now reads:
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID);

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// gives us an auth instance
const auth = getAuth(app);

// in order to use this auth instance elsewhere
export default auth;

In conclusion, after I made these adaptations and restarted my Vite server, the correct environment variables were in place.
